Omitting regular terms in OPE
Consider the OPE of two operators $$A(z)B(w)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^N \frac{\{AB\}_{-n}(w)}{(z-w)^n}.$$
We omit $\{AB\}_n(w)$ terms for $n>0$ since in the sense of OPE what we only care is the behavior when $z\to w$.
This however doesn't justify omitting $\{AB\}_0(w)$ (which is the definition of normal order in big yellow book), while everybody puts them in regular term without reason. This term doesn't depend on $z\to w$, and under this definition of normal order it's not obvious to me that its VEV vanishes. It's most likely that $\langle \{AB\}_0(w)\rangle=0$ but why? (For your reference the VEV or contraction of operators is defined using path integral.)
Can somebody help explain why this term is not considered in OPE? More restrictions such as A and B are primary are also welcomed.
It would be actually better if there are reasons to disregard all regular terms together. One (definitely incorrect) possibility to take away all regular terms is that VEV of operator product can be written as some contour integral around $w$, but this makes no sense for otherwise we only need the term with $n=1$.

Hi moph. Welcome to Phys.SE. 1. Briefly speaking, the regular terms in an OPE are in principle there. Be aware that some authors may use a shorthand notation, where regular terms are implicitly implied. 2. For why the expectation value of normal-ordered expression vanishes, see my Phys.SE answer here.

Ok, but my question is why we don't care about them in OPE.

These terms are absolutely important and are definitely considered in the OPE.

@Prahar Thanks, and this matches my initial thought. But then why there's nobody taking OPE to full expansion? For the simplest example, I can't find anywhere the full expansion of TTOPE including regular terms.

The full expansion is often theory dependent. It is also not needed for many calculations, and in those cases it is omitted. In most examples that you have studied, you can (and should) prove that the regular terms are irrelevant for that calculation. If you do conformal bootstrap then all the regular terms are necessary.

"We can ignore regular terms in an OPE" is often made as a blanket statement but we need to be more careful. It's better to say that we can do this if we're trying to compute correlation functions of conserved currents (those with $h = 0$ or $\bar{h} = 0$). The most universal place to start is by looking at the stress tensor. Its OPE with a Virasoro primary is
\begin{align}
T(z) \phi(w, \bar{w}) = \frac{h_\phi \phi(w, \bar{w})}{(z - w)^2} + \frac{\partial \phi(w, \bar{w})}{z - w} + \dots
\end{align}
where we need to include regular terms. One will survive $z \to w$ and the rest will vanish. But when this is inside a correlation function, we will have
\begin{align}
\left < T(z) \phi_1(w_1, \bar{w}_1) \dots \phi(w_n, \bar{w}_n) \right > = \sum_i \left [ \frac{h_i}{(z - w_i)^2} + \frac{\partial_i}{z - w_i} \right ] \left < \phi_1(w_1, \bar{w}_1) \dots \phi(w_n, \bar{w}_n) \right >
\end{align}
and not any regular terms. This is because the variation of a Virasoro primary under a conformal transformation is given by the two expressions
\begin{align}
\oint_w \frac{dz}{2\pi i} \epsilon(z)T(z) \phi(w, \bar{w}), \quad h_\phi \partial \epsilon(w) \phi(w, \bar{w}) + \epsilon(w) \partial \phi(w, \bar{w}).
\end{align}
If you tried to add some $(z - w_i)^k \partial_i^{k + 2}$ term to the Ward identity, integrating it against a sufficiently singular $\epsilon(z)$ would produce a variation with more than the two terms above. You can then keep going to compute things like
\begin{align}
\left < L_{-k} \phi_1(w_1, \bar{w}_1) \dots \phi(w_n, \bar{w}_n) \right > = \oint_{w_1} \frac{dz}{2\pi i} (z - w_1)^{1 - k} \left < T(z) \phi_1(w_1, \bar{w}_1) \dots \phi(w_n, \bar{w}_n) \right >.
\end{align}
The best way to do this is to deform the contour so that it encircles $w_2, \dots w_n$ and use the Ward identity with only two terms near each singularity.

From your words, $\langle T\phi\rangle$ has zero contribution from regular part of $T\phi$ OPE, which is good. But what I'm asking is whether $\langle A(z)B(w)\rangle$ has also no regular contribution for general OPE of (primary or descendant) fields. (probably not the case?)

In a correlation function of two operators, only a single term in the OPE contributes... the identity. Assuming you are in a unitary theory, this will be present for $A = B$ and absent for $A \neq B$. For a correlation function with many operators, this can always be computed recursively by using the OPE in a single channel. And this will always require infinitely many regular terms even if the operators are conserved currents. What I tried to explain in my post is that there is another method when they are currents which involves using the OPE in many channels but only singular terms.

I'm quite interesting in your comment "in a unitary theory, identity will only be present for $A=B$". Would you mind sharing where statement is proved?

Unitarity tells you that the ground state is conformally invariant (lowest dimension operators is the identity). But I was being a bit too fast. Two-point functions with respect to this vacuum don't literally require $A = B$. They just require $A$ and $B$ to have the same scaling dimension. But once this is the case, you can take linear combination and use an orthonormal basis of two-point functions.
